# Navigator.serviceWorker.controller only works in webroot

Tags: service-worker

I am trying to get a`ServiceWorker` to work from a subdirectory in webroot named `appdashboard` ... the serviceworker installs, runs and is visible from `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`, but its `Navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is null so I cannot communicate with it.  If I don't restrict the scope (and move my serviceworker file to webroot) it works fine.

```
   const serviceWorker = navigator
        .serviceWorker
        .register('appdashboard/dashboard_serviceworker.js', { scope: 'http://localhost/appdashboard/' })
        .then((swReg) => {
            console.log('[Service Worker (Dashboard)] service worker is registered', swReg);
            swRegistration = swReg;

            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller != null) {
                console.log("controller is working")
            }

            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller == null) {
                console.log("controller is NULL!") // <<<< its null :(
            }
    })
```

I simplified my `serviceworker` as much as possible to diagnose the issue, and controller is null even with this bare bones worker

```
self.addEventListener('message', function (event) { 
    console.log('got message')
});


self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    console.log('serviceworker activate')
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim()); // Become available to all pages
});


self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    console.log('install')
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    console.log('fetch')
});

self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
    console.log('received push')
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log('registered notification click!')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `MVC` routing so that my URL path was `localhost/dashboard` but my file structure was `/appdashboard/`, now I serve up an index.html from `/appdashboard/` webroot and controller initializes.

This is the line that set me on the right path.

> Remember the scope, when included, uses the page's location as its
>   base. Alternatively, if this code were included in a page at
>   example.com/product/description.html, the scope of './' would mean
>   that the service worker only applies to resources under
>   example.com/product.